# Why do I keep getting Missing a temporary folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, file-upload, tmp

I'm new to WordPress but I kept getting an access error for every file I uploaded. I searched and found out that this was because I did not have permissions on the temporary directory and it was suggested that I changed permissions on that directory. I did that but now I get a "missing a temporary folder" error whenever I try to upload any file. I am using Windows Server 2012 IIS 6.

This is my `php.ini` code on the `upload_tmp_dir` variable:

```
; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
upload_tmp_dir = C:\Windows\Temp
```

Comment: it is highly unlikely that your web server has access to the `C:\Windows` directory. You should instead change that path to reflect something that it might have access to, such as `C:\httpd`. Also, never let your web server haccess to the Windows directory. Basically asking for trouble there.

Comment: That was exactly it... Weird thing was that it came by default... Thanks a lot.